# How to execute a compiled C program in Linux terminal

Tags: linux, c

```
#include<stdio.h>
main()
    {
        int a,b,c;
        printf("enter the value of a and b for addition:\n");
        scanf("%d %d",&a,&b);
        c=a+b;
        printf("Addition of the numbers is:%d",c);
    }
```

After typing program in gedit I given output command `gcc o- filename filename.c` then again I gave command `./filename` then it is telling `permission denied` then I again gave command `chmod +x filename` .Then the computer is saying that `syntax error near unexpected token '"(enter values of a and b for addition:\n");`

Answer (score 3):

Simply just do `gcc filename.c && ./a.out`. This will compile and run the code using GCC.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to run the wrong file. The compiler wrote your program to `filename`, but all error messages look as if you were trying to run the *source code*, `filename.c`, directly.

(Make sure you've ran the compiler correctly; too – it's `gcc -o`, not `gcc o-`.)

Comment: Your hypothesis is supported by the fact that the given `gcc` invocation cannot reasonably have succeeded; gcc would almost certainly have balked at the `o-` (unless there are valid source code files named `o-`, `filename` and `filename.c` in the current directory; in that case the output binary would be named `a.out` for historical reasons). (Haha, I see now that you edited that into your answer while I was busy typing up the comment.)

Answer (score 1):

You used wrong input  `gcc o- filename filename.c`, first of all it should be `-o` (not `o-` as you wrongly provided), and it is better to write in this order `gcc filename.c -o filename`.

Then `./filename`, no need to make `chmod +x filename` after `gcc`.

Comment: Why is it better to provide the -o argument after the list of functions?

Comment: technically it doesn't matter, it is just a style, from left to right: input -> output. I believe it is better visualization.

Comment: You don't say that. You say it is better, not that it makes more sense stylistically.

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid all of that by installing `make` and then you can just `make filename`

`Make` is smart enough to look for `filename.c` and then create filename and mark filename `chmod +x`

Compiles the app, takes care of naming and marks the file as executable all in one go. It’s wonderful and takes the manual drudgery out of compiling.

Comment: At the risk of splitting hairs, this is not 100% correct.  If you say `make filename`, and `filename.c` exists, then `make` knows to invoke the C compiler.  Subsequently, if the compilation succeeds, *the compiler* changes the mode of the binary executable file.  As [Ruslan Gerasimov says](https://superuser.com/q/784815/150988#785371), if you do `gcc filename.c -o filename` and it succeeds, you don't need to do `chmod +x`.

Comment: … as discussed [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/165240/23408).